# Java - download .json file using HttpServletResponse,but find file content contain {}

Tags: java, json, servlets

I have written code to download json file here is the code

```
      @RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void download(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
        text.add("a");
        text.add("b");
        String textString = JSON.toJSONString(text);

        final Path path = Files.createTempFile("text", ".json");
        byte[] buf = textString.getBytes();
        Files.write(path, buf);

        response.reset();
        response.getOutputStream().write(buf);
        response.addHeader("content-type", "application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8");
        String fileNameEncode = URLEncoder.encode("text", "UTF-8");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileNameEncode + ".json");

    }
```

file content should return :

```
["a","b"]
```

but return:

```
["a","b"]{}
```

Comment: Your question is implying that `textContentListJsonString` is correct and that `response.getOutputStream().write(buf);` is wrong. But this is impossible. Please improve your question. This is a problem in *either* the `ObjectMapper` *or* in the `HttpServletResponse` but impossibly _both_. All we know is that `HttpServletResponse` is merely writing whatever it is told to write (and has done that for ages), so it's much more likely that `ObjectMapper` part is wrong.

Comment: [edit] your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I find tempFile content is right,but download file is wrong